# Broken Javascript because of superfish.com

Tags: javascript

Recently a lot of javascript breaks because of some JS that's being loaded from superfish.com.

I have tried googling it, but it's quite obscure. I have seen other people complaining and it was because of extensions/addons. I don't think that's my problem.

I also don't know where it comes from.. I was hoping anyone else had this problem and/or knows the solution.. or at least some direction to look at.

At the moment my suspicion goes to Google. Superfish.com seems to be some kind of 'searching' thing and I have it when a website loads Google Adsense or when I CDN load jQuery from the Google servers..

P.s. This is not about the jQuery plugin Superfish. P.p.s. I understand this might be the wrong stackexchange, but I have faith in this community!

Comment: Is it possible that superfish has installed some type of addon in your browser? It might something that loads as a result of a request that is being generated by a addon, rather than javascript located within the webpage itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I dind't check well. It was infact brought upon by an en extenstion called X-Notifier (for Gmail and stuff)

Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Superfish is not malicious.  It is a small startup in Silicon valley that is trying to make a Visual Search engine. I imagine Google must be using it in one of it's scripts. Usually, the primary culprit is an app they have called "Window Shopper"

If you have this window shopper, google "remove window shopper" and you should get some good hits on how to disable it for your respective browser+os

Comment: I removed 'malicious' from my comment. I should have googled before I accused.